# Using "pub serve", how do I serve a root resource?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I am using "pub serve" to serve my Dart web app.  Pub is running at `http://localhost:8080/`.

I can access my app at `http://localhost:8080/index.html` which loads the `index.html` file in the `web` directory in my project.

I would like to be able to load the same `index.html` directly from `http://locahost:8080/`.  How do I do accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

["pub serve" should support index.html and directory listing](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15020)